# Disable ToolStripMenuItem highlight?

Tags: c#, winforms, menustrip, toolstripmenu

I have an application with a MenuStrip and every time I hover my mouse over a MenuItem, it highlights blue.

I have tried to change the BackColor and ForeColor but that wasn't the problem.

Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would be incredibly un-useful to the end user:

```
internal class NoHighlightRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer {
  protected override void OnRenderMenuItemBackground(ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.OwnerItem == null) {
      base.OnRenderMenuItemBackground(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Then apply it to your MenuStrip:

```
menuStrip1.Renderer = new NoHighlightRenderer();
```

Comment: I just used this code for the same reason and I hade to use 

if(e.Item.OwnerItem != null)

Comment: Good find.  Change the `if` to `if(e.Item.Enabled)` if you just want to ignore disabled (e.g. "label") items.